# how to read line by line using fread in c

Tags: c

I have a problem with fread, my program only read the first line in the file. im using structure to save the data to file and get the data temporary to check the status. if using fgets i don't know how to take the each data in my structure  to the temporary structure to check

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct data
{ 
char uname[30], pass[30], nama[30], alamat[30], nomer[30];
} real,temp;

int userchecker(FILE *ptr);
void regist(FILE *ptr);
int main(){
    FILE *ptr;
    printf("\n\nSelamat Datang Di D'Medicine");
    printf("\n\n============================\n");

    printf("Silahkan ");

    printf("Username :");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &real.uname);
    if(userchecker(ptr) == 0){
    printf("====registrasi akun======\n");
    printf("Nama :");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &real.nama);
    printf("pass :");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &real.pass);
    printf("Alamat :");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &real.alamat);
    printf("Nomer Telepon :");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &real.nomer);
    regist(ptr);
    }else{
        printf("sudah terdaftar\n");
        printf("%s %s\n", temp.uname,temp.nama);
    }
return 0;
}
int userchecker(FILE *ptr){
    int flag = 0;
    ptr = fopen("data.bin","rb");
    if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("file error\n");
        flag = 1;
    }else{
        while(fread(&temp, sizeof(struct data),1,ptr)){
            if(strcmp(real.uname,temp.uname)==0){
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
            else{
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1){
            printf("data tidak ditemukan\n");
            return 0;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    fclose(ptr);
    }
    
}
void regist(FILE *ptr){
    ptr = fopen("data.bin","ab");
    fwrite(&real, sizeof(struct data), 1, ptr);
    fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, ptr);
    printf("data registed");
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: `fread` doesn't read lines - It reads items of `size` size. What seems to be the problem with your program? You may want to change all your `scanf`s to take a `char*` instead though

Comment: You write \n into the file after each record, but you don't handle \n when you're reading, therefore each record after the first is off by one character in all its fields.

Comment: `od -tx8 -w30 data.bin` will give you a hex dump of your file, with 30 chars per line.